# SQL Server - Run query with variable that ranges from 1 to 1000

Tags: sql-server

Newb here, self taught on a need to basis.

I need to run a query a 1000 times, with a single variable, from 1 to 1000.

Something like

declare @number int
set @number=1
update mytable set column1=xx where column2=@number

And then I would change @number to 2 and so on.

I need some sort of cursor that will run this with @number from 1 to 1000.

The query itself is a bit more complicated but that's the gist of it.
I know I have to run a cursor but I never really understood them from reading online.

Comment: Cursors are for iterating a result of a query. To loop numbers, use a while loop and increase a counter inside it.

Comment: Another way to do all the job at once - to populate list of numbers with CTE+ROW_NUMBER and join your `mytable`

Comment: Are you really sure you need a loop? So many times I hear that and in the end a loop is not needed. Very rarely do you actually need a loop to update a bunch of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @number INT;
SET @number = 1

WHILE @number <= 1000
BEGIN
   UPDATE tblMyTable 
     SET Column1 = 999
   WHERE Column2 = @number
   SET @number = @number + 1
END
```